# How to fix 'Unsupported media type" error on python POST request to Twilio

Tags: python, post, python-requests, twilio, media-type

I have been following Twilio's [Quickstart page for their Functions API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/quickstart#create-a-function).

I am stuck at the part where I am supposed to manually upload the Function JS file.

Their POST examples use cURL and node.js but I am using Python 3.6:

```
# Manually upload the subscription function file
upload_url = f'https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/{sub_service_sid}/Functions/{sub_function_sid}/Versions'
function_request = requests.post(
                                upload_url,
                                files    = {'subscription_function_file': open('subscriptionFunction.js', 'rb')},
                                auth     = (account_sid, auth_token),
                                headers  = {
                                    'content-type': 'application/javascript',
                                    'path': '/subscription-function',
                                    'visibility': 'public'
                                }
                            )
```

In both examples, they declare the content type as `application/javascript`. However, I get this error when I do the same:

```
{"status":415,"message":"Unsupported media type","detail":"The server does not support the media type transmitted in the request.","code":20415,"moreInfo":"https://www/twilio.com/docs/errors/20415"}
```

That URL throws a `404` so I went digging in Twilio's [Error Dictionary](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors) but that code is not listed. Furthermore, `application/javascript` is absent from their [supported media types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types) page.

Am I uploading the file incorrectly? Or is their tutorial wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you may have translated some of the curl request to the wrong parts of a request made with `requests` and I think this is causing the issue. You don't want to set the request type to be `application/javascript` that wants to be the type of the file you are uploading. You can set this as part of the `files` tuple.

You don't want to send the other bits of data, `Path` and `Visibility` as headers either, they should be part of the `data` so they become part of the request body.

Try something like this instead:

```py
upload_url = f'https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/{sub_service_sid}/Functions/{sub_function_sid}/Versions'

files = { 'Content': ('subscriptionFunction.js', open('subscriptionFunction.js', 'rb'), 'application/javascript') }

function_request = requests.post(
                                upload_url,
                                files    = files,
                                auth     = (account_sid, auth_token),
                                data     = {
                                    'Path': '/subscription-function',
                                    'Visibility': 'public'
                                }
                            )
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for answering. I went ahead and tried your suggestions and I am getting this now: 
`{"message": "[Content may not be null, Content may not be null]", "code":20001, "user_error":true, "http_status_code":400, "params":{}}`

I haven't been able to pinpoint what I'm missing

Comment: It seems to work when I post to http://httpbin.org/post but not the necessary Twilio URL

Comment: Ah, I think I used the wrong parameter name for the file content. It should be `files = { 'Content': ('subscriptionFunction.js', ...` instead of "file". Give that a try and let me know how you get on.